# Doubled quotes when using sqlite_escape_string

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm escaping blog posts with sqlite_escape_string(), and connecting to the database using the old object-oriented way.

(Yes, I know, I should use PDO, I'll get to that later; converting this script would take quite a while.)

When I have data like: `It's raining cats and dogs!`, it saves  this to the database: `It''s raining cats and dogs!`. The problem is that it comes out of the database like that, and stripslashes() doesn't undo it. Magic Quotes is turned off.

Every time I recall that data from the database and save it again, it adds more single-quotes. How would I stop it from doing that?

Here's the abridged submission code:

```
        # Grab the data from form and escape the text
        $title = sqlite_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
        $text = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['text']);
        # Query for previous data
        $result = @$dbh->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=".$id);
        # Fetch previous data
        while($past = $result->fetchObject()) {
            $ptitle = $past->title;
            $ptext = $past->post;
        }
        # Set a base query to modify
        $base = "UPDATE posts SET ";
        # Run through scenarios
            if(stripslashes($ptitle) !== $title) { $base .= "title='".sqlite_escape_string($title)."', "; }
            if(stripslashes($ptext) !== $text) { $base .= "text='".sqlite_escape_string($text)."', "; }
            }
        # Remove last comma & space
        $base = substr($base, 0, -2);
        $base .= " WHERE id=".(int)$id;
        # Execute modified query
        @$dbh->query($base);
```

And here's the code that reads the data back:

```
# Sanitize and set variables
$start = (int)$start;
$limit = (int)$limit;
$start = ($start - 1) * $limit;
$dbh = $this->dbh;
$this->limit = $limit;

# Query the database for post data
$this->result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id desc LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit);

public function loop() {
    # Do we have any posts?
    if(!empty($this->result)) {
        # Convert query results into something usable
        $this->cur_result = $this->result->fetchObject();
        # This while loop will remain true until we run out of posts
        while($post = $this->cur_result) {
            return true;
        }
        # At which point it turns false, ending the loop in the template file
        return false;
    }
    # We don't have any posts :(
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function content($excerpt = '') {
    # We didn't screw up and keep an empty query, did we?
    if(!empty($this->cur_result)) {
        echo stripslashes($this->cur_result->post);
    }
}
```

Comment: A very trivial solution is str_replace("''", "'", $string)

Comment: If you want code, you'll have to give me a few minutes to pull out chunks of code.

Comment: @Aurelio, he needs to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen as I sayd (infact I post it as a comment) that was a VERY TRIVIAL solution. No intended to solve the problem with that. I post it just for have a quick solution in the case the problem is urgent.

Comment: It's not urgent :) I've updated the question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are escaping the data twice.

At the beginning of your code you have:

```
$title = sqlite_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
$text = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['text']);
```

And then in the insert you have:

```
if(stripslashes($ptitle) !== $title) { $base .= "title='".sqlite_escape_string($title)."', "; }
if(stripslashes($ptext) !== $text) { $base .= "text='".sqlite_escape_string($text)."', "; }
```

Remove the sqlite_escape_string from the if statements and I think the result will come out correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have [magic_quotes_sybase](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sybase.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-sybase) on.  Post the values of:

```
echo ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase');
echo get_magic_quotes_gpc() // Probably not relevant, but may as well be thorough.
```

Both should be 0.

EDIT: You're clearly double-escaping both `$text` and `$title`:

```
    $title = sqlite_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
    $text = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['text']);
...
            if(stripslashes($ptitle) !== $title) { $base .= "title='".sqlite_escape_string($title)."', "; }
            if(stripslashes($ptext) !== $text) { $base .= "text='".sqlite_escape_string($text)."', "; }
```

As you know, prepared statements are the best solution.  But if you're going to use escaping, escape every variable at the last possible moment.  That's right before the DB call, *not* when you're reading input.

If you're using escaping or prepared statements correctly, you will never have to call stripslashes or remove extra quotes when reading from the db.

Comment: Nope; magic_quotes_gpc, magic_quotes_runtime, and magic_quotes_sybase are all off.